# How do you sort a dataframe with the integer in a column with strings and integers on every row?

Tags: python, pandas, string, sorting, integer

How would you sort the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc_1.2.6','abc_1.2.60','abc_1.2.7','abc_1.2.9','abc_1.3.0','abc_1.3.10','abc_1.3.100','abc_1.3.11'], 'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

>>>
    a           b
0   abc_1.2.6   1
1   abc_1.2.60  2
2   abc_1.2.7   3
3   abc_1.2.9   4
4   abc_1.3.0   5
5   abc_1.3.10  6
6   abc_1.3.100 7
7   abc_1.3.11  8
```

to achieve this output?

```
>>>
    a           b
0   abc_1.2.6   1
1   abc_1.2.7   3
2   abc_1.2.9   4
3   abc_1.2.60  2
4   abc_1.3.0   5
5   abc_1.3.10  6
6   abc_1.3.11  8
7   abc_1.3.100 7
```

I understand that integers in strings can be accessed through string transformations, however I'm unsure how to handle this in a dataframe. Obviously `df.sort_values(by=['a'],ignore_index=True)` is unhelpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to use is [`natsorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/5.4.1/natsorted.html) with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) :

```
#pip install natsort
from natsort import natsorted
​
out = df.iloc[natsorted(range(len(df)), key=lambda x: df.loc[x, "a"])]
```

Or even shorter, as suggested by @[*Stef*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080723/stef), use [`natsort_key`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/5.4.1/natsort_key.html) as a key of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) :

```
from natsort import natsort_key

out = df.sort_values(by="a", key=natsort_key, ignore_index=True)
```

Output :

```
print(out)
             a  b
0    abc_1.2.6  1
1    abc_1.2.7  3
2    abc_1.2.9  4
3   abc_1.2.60  2
4    abc_1.3.0  5
5   abc_1.3.10  6
6   abc_1.3.11  8
7  abc_1.3.100  7
```

Comment: Alternatively `from natsort import natsort_key; df.sort_values(by='a', key=natsort_key)`

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I edited the response to fully produce the question's desired output. See `ignore_index=True` in the function.

Comment: Good catch and edit approved ;) I missed that you don't care about the index in your output.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the `key` function to the values before sorting:

```
df = (df.sort_values(by=['a'], ignore_index=True,
                     key=lambda x: x.map(lambda v:
                                         tuple(map(int, v[4:].split('.'))))))
```

---

```
             a  b
0    abc_1.2.6  1
1    abc_1.2.7  3
2    abc_1.2.9  4
3   abc_1.2.60  2
4    abc_1.3.0  5
5   abc_1.3.10  6
6   abc_1.3.11  8
7  abc_1.3.100  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way by using `str.findall()` and `explode()`

```
df.sort_values('a',key = lambda x: x.str.findall(r'\d+').explode().astype(int).groupby(level=0).agg(tuple))
```

Output:

```
             a  b
0    abc_1.2.6  1
2    abc_1.2.7  3
3    abc_1.2.9  4
1   abc_1.2.60  2
4    abc_1.3.0  5
5   abc_1.3.10  6
7   abc_1.3.11  8
6  abc_1.3.100  7
```